# How to center all thumbnails that goes external links in wordpress posts?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'd like to center all of the text & image bodies (or content body before "read more") of all posts (in single.php) at once with simple (or advanced) css code.

I've tried this css code:

`.entry-content{text-align:center !important;}`

I expect to see thumbnails (external sources) to be centered but they are not. Only text content has been centered. But i want the external thumbs too. How to do?

Comment: there is nothing more than above code we just need to add simple one too

Answer (score 0):

Apply "display:inline-block" style for inner nodes.

Comment: Please upload your code here, so that I can help you.

Comment: .entry-content{text-align:center !important;}